# How to tell from Npgsql exception if the call is worth a retry (transient fault strategy)

Tags: c#, postgresql, microservices, npgsql, polly

I'm writing a service which will be connecting to a remote postgres server.
I'm looking for a good way to determine which exceptions should be treated as transient (worth retrying), and how to define an appropriate policy for connecting to a remote database.

The service is using Npgsql for the data access.
The documentation says that Npgsql will throw a PostgresException for sql errors and an NpgsqlException for "server related issues".

So far the best I have been able to come up with is to assume all exceptions that are not PostgresExceptions should be treated as possibly transient, worth retrying, but a PostgresException would mean that there is something wrong with the query and that retrying would not help.  Am I correct in this assumption?

I am using Polly to create a Retry and Circuit Breaker policy.
Thus, my policy looks like this:

```
Policy.Handle<Exception>( AllButPotgresExceptions()) // if its a postgres exception we know its not going to work even with a retry, so don't
                       .WaitAndRetryAsync(new[]
                       {
                           TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1),
                           TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2),
                           TimeSpan.FromSeconds(4)
                       }, onRetry: (exception, span) => Log.Warning(exception, "Postgres Retry Failure: "))
                    .WrapAsync(
                           Policy.Handle<Exception>( AllButPotgresExceptions())
                               .AdvancedCircuitBreakerAsync(
                                   failureThreshold:.7, 
                                   samplingDuration: TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30), 
                                   minimumThroughput: 20, 
                                   durationOfBreak: TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30), 
                                   onBreak: (ex, timeSpan, context) => Log.Warning(ex, "Postres Circuit Breaker Broken: "), 
                                   onReset: (context) => Log.Warning("Postres Circuit Breaker Reset: "), 
                                   onHalfOpen: () => Log.Warning("Postres Circuit Breaker Half Open: ")
                               )));
        }
    }

    private static Func<Exception, bool> AllButPotgresExceptions()
    {
        return ex => ex.GetType() != typeof(PostgresException);
    }
```

Is there a better way to determine which errors may be transient?

UPDATE:

Following Shay's suggestions I opened a new issue in Npgsql and updated my Policy to look like this:

```
public static Policy PostresTransientFaultPolicy
    {
        get
        {
            return postgresTransientPolicy ?? (postgresTransientPolicy = Policy.Handle<Exception>( PostgresDatabaseTransientErrorDetectionStrategy())
                       .WaitAndRetryAsync(
                            retryCount: 10, 
                            sleepDurationProvider: retryAttempt => ExponentialBackoff(retryAttempt, 1.4), 
                            onRetry: (exception, span) => Log.Warning(exception, "Postgres Retry Failure: "))
                    .WrapAsync(
                           Policy.Handle<Exception>( PostgresDatabaseTransientErrorDetectionStrategy())
                               .AdvancedCircuitBreakerAsync(
                                   failureThreshold:.4, 
                                   samplingDuration: TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30), 
                                   minimumThroughput: 20, 
                                   durationOfBreak: TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30), 
                                   onBreak: (ex, timeSpan, context) => Log.Warning(ex, "Postres Circuit Breaker Broken: "), 
                                   onReset: (context) => Log.Warning("Postres Circuit Breaker Reset: "), 
                                   onHalfOpen: () => Log.Warning("Postres Circuit Breaker Half Open: ")
                               )));
        }
    }

    private static TimeSpan ExponentialBackoff(int retryAttempt, double exponent)
    {
        //TODO add random %20 variance on the exponent
        return TimeSpan.FromSeconds(Math.Pow(retryAttempt, exponent));
    }

    private static Func<Exception, bool> PostgresDatabaseTransientErrorDetectionStrategy()
    {
        return (ex) =>
        {                
            //if it is not a postgres exception we must assume it will be transient
            if (ex.GetType() != typeof(PostgresException))
                return true;

            var pgex = ex as PostgresException;
            switch (pgex.SqlState)
            {
                case "53000":   //insufficient_resources
                case "53100":   //disk_full
                case "53200":   //out_of_memory
                case "53300":   //too_many_connections
                case "53400":   //configuration_limit_exceeded
                case "57P03":   //cannot_connect_now
                case "58000":   //system_error
                case "58030":   //io_error

                //These next few I am not sure whether they should be treated as transient or not, but I am guessing so

                case "55P03":   //lock_not_available
                case "55006":   //object_in_use
                case "55000":   //object_not_in_prerequisite_state
                case "08000":   //connection_exception
                case "08003":   //connection_does_not_exist
                case "08006":   //connection_failure
                case "08001":   //sqlclient_unable_to_establish_sqlconnection
                case "08004":   //sqlserver_rejected_establishment_of_sqlconnection
                case "08007":   //transaction_resolution_unknown
                    return true;
            }

            return false;
        };
    }
```

Comment: Where did you find this error code list? I'm trying to find EndOfStreamException error code

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your approach is good. NpgsqlException usually means a network/IO error, although you can examine the inner exception and check for IOException to be sure.

PostgresException is thrown when PostgreSQL reports an error, which in most cases is a problem with the query. However, there may be some transient server-side issues (e.g. too many connections), you can examine the SQL error code for that - see [the PG docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/errcodes-appendix.html).

It may be a good idea to add an `IsTransient` property to these exceptions, encoding these checks inside PostgreSQL itself - you're welcome to open an issue for that on the Npgsql repo.

Comment: Thanks for your help and suggestions.  I will update my policy to look for some specific error codes as well, and then post my modified policy here.

Comment: Great. Please also open an issue on https://github.com/npgsql/npgsql - we can incorporate your policy into Npgsql itself.

Comment: From my experience, the most important transient error is the one with code 40001 (transaction serialization failure).

Comment: @OlivierMATROT and others, the github issue tracking this feature is https://github.com/npgsql/npgsql/issues/1495, can you please post there?